# How to use regex in python in getting a string between two characters?

Tags: python

I have this as my input

content = 'abc.zip'\n

I want to take out abc out of it . How do I do it using regex in python ?

Edit :

No this is not a homework question . I am trying to automate something and I am stuck at a certain point so that I can make the automate generic to any zip file I have  .

```
os.system('python unzip.py -z data/ABC.zip -o data/')
```

After I take in the zip file , I unzip it .
I am planning to make it generic , by getting the filename from the directory the zip file was put in and then provide the file name to the upper stated syntax to unzip it

Comment: More details please. Is it always the string ``'abc'`` you want removed? Or is it everything before the dot? Is this a filename, or just a random string? The best tool for the job (almost certainly *not* regular expressions) depends on these details.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, you should tag it as `homework`.

Comment: To be clear, is it `content = 'abc.zip'\n` (with that newline outside the quotes) or `input = r"content = 'abc.zip'\n"`?

Comment: @Blair I have edited my question . A non re approach can also do .

Comment: You're trying to call a Python script from within a Python script? There is undoubtedly a better way of doing this!

Comment: I can use the unzip library of python , but thats not the problem here .

Comment: @Blair's answer solves the problem of extracting the filename. Calling [`ZipFile.extractall()`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) sounds like a better plan!

Comment: os.system('python unzip.py -z data/\/'an'/\ -o data/')
where an = abc.zip . Got syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to break up parts of a path, you may find the [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) module to be useful.  It has nice abstractions with clear semantics that are easy to use.

Comment: Ok then I would tell the bigger problem here . My file structure is this data/Abc.zip . My script doesn't really know the name of the zip file . How do I unzip the file using os.path and also extract the name of the zip file

Comment: @user794916: Please update your question to include all the pertinent information.

Answer (score 4):

As I implied in my comment, regular expressions are unlikely to be the best tool for the job (unless there is some artificial restriction on the problem, or it is far more complex than your example). The standard string and/or path libraries provide functions which should do what you are after. To better illustrate how these work, I'll use the following definition of `content` instead:

```
>>> content = 'abc.def.zip'
```

If its a file, and you want the name and extension:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> filename, extension = os.path.splitext(content)
>>> print filename
abc.def
>>> print extension
.zip
```

If it is a string, and you want to remove the substring 'abc':

```
>>> noabc = content.replace('abc', '')
>>> print noabc
.def.zip
```

If you want to break it up on each occurrence of a period;

```
>>> broken = content.split('.')
>>> print broken
['abc', 'def', 'zip']
```

If it has multiple periods, and you want to break it on the first or last one:

```
>>> broken = content.split('.', 1)
>>> print broken
['abc', 'def.zip']
>>> broken = content.rsplit('.', 1)
>>> print broken
['abc.def', 'zip']
```

Comment: How do I insert the filename in this statement os.system('python unzip.py -z data/Abc.zip -o data/') . In the place of Abc.zip , that file name

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Changed the regexp to match for "content = 'abc.zip\n'" instead of the string "abc.zip".

```
import re 

#Matching for "content = 'abc.zip\n'"
matches = re.match("(?P<filename>.*).zip\n'$", "content = 'abc.zip\n'")
matches = matches.groupdict()
print matches

#Matching for "abc.zip"    
matches = re.match("(?P<filename>.*).zip$", "abc.zip")
matches = matches.groupdict()
print matches
```

Output:

```
{'filename': 'abc'}
```

This will print the matches of everything before `.zip`. You can access everything like a regular dictionary.

Comment: I thought that content was a variable. And that the string was "abc.zip". I'll edit my answer after that the string is what you wrote.

Comment: @Johnysweb Yeah, it's very unclear :) I'll have to edit my answer to match for both.